# How to estimate pigeonhole principle?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle, balls-in-bins

I was thinking about this after my professor mentioned the pigeonhole principle in class. Let's say we have $N$ items and $M$ containers. Here we assume $N > M$. We will randomly place each of the $N$ items into the $M$ containers. Is there a way to estimate the number of empty lists, as well as the length of the longest list?

I've tried looking up the pigeonhole principle online, but I could not find any algorithms or formulae.

Comment: The pigeonhoile principle can only tell you that there is at least one nonempty list (because $N>0$) and at most $M$ nonempty lists (becasue $N\ge M$). More interestngly it tells you that the longest list is at least $\lceil N/M\rceil$ items long (and at most $N$). If you say *randomly* you may instead be interested in a probability theoretic investigation of *expected* counts/ list lengths?

Comment: This is called the “balls in bins” problem; that's what you should search for. It has been carefully studied, because it's extremely important in the analysis of hashing and load-balancing algorithms.

Comment: @MJD ahh okay I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry I can't remember the answer to your question just now.

Comment: we can say as $N\to\infty$, the number of empty lists $\to0$ and the longest list $\to N/M$

Answer (score 0):

There are many versions of pigeonhole principle, Here are just some:

- If the number of objects exceeds the number of containers  at least $1$ container, will contain at least $2$ objects.
- If the number of objects,  is greater than $k$ times the number of containers, at least $1$ container will have, at least $k+1$ objects in it
- if you put $q_1+q_2+\cdots q_n -n+1$ objects in $n$ containers, at least $1$ of the containers say container $l$, will have at least $q_l$ objects in it.

  - etc.

I believe you want the probabilistic pigeonhole principle, which I believe is along the lines of:

- If all boxes have probability $m$ of being choosen to place an object in it, there will be at least one box with at least $n$ objects in it, $m^n$ of the time.